# Is there a way to hook into the Flutter build similarly to Gradle tasks or Xcode build steps?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to do a few things during the Flutter build process, let's say, inject an external resource/file/asset into the final App.
Is that even possible?
I know I can do this using Gradle tasks directly in the Gradle file or Xcode build steps but in this case, I'd need to have a custom solution per platform which is not scalable when supporting all the platforms.
I also know that you can have a `dev_dependencies` but that requires the user to execute such a plugin manually besides that this is executed before or after the build, but I'd like to do this during the build process so I can influence the final App.
Thanks a bunch.

I tried using `dev_dependencies`, patching the Gradle script, patching the Xcode build steps.